# iOS 9 - "domainIdentifier" for CSSearchableItem

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

in the init for a CSSearchableItem, one of the parameters is a "domainIdentifier" which Apple writes in its docs is the item's "associated ID." What is this?

Answer (score 3):

*domainIdentifier* is a way to **group** several searchable items together.
You will use it to restore/update/delete groups of items, when needed.

Comment: You say to "delete groups of items" - what do you mean by that? DO you mean delete all index items for the app or delete a section of the index data for the app? Because otherwise, whats the point of the ```deleteAllSearchableItemsWithCompletionHandler``` method which doesn't require any identifiers?

Answer (score 1):

The Domain identifier is the group name to be indexed. 
For example if you index all contacts from app use can use like as follows:

```
searchableItems=[[CSSearchableItem alloc]initWithUniqueIdentifier:identifier domainIdentifier:@"contacts" attributeSet:attributeSet];
```

The domain identifier name is used to easily delete all index in that domain like this :

```
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex]deleteSearchableItemsWithDomainIdentifiers:@[@"contacts"] completionHandler:^(NSError * __nullable error) {

        if (error!=nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        }
        else
        {
            // Indexes deleted successfully
        }
    }];
```

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, whats the point of the ```deleteAllSearchableItemsWithCompletionHandler``` method then? That doesn't need any identifiers???